# How to create a Java Hexadecimal Array

Tags: java, hex, bit-manipulation

This does not seem to be appropriate. Is there a way to create a *hexadecimal* array?

```
 float[] bitBytes = {0x80, 0x40, 0x20, 0x10, 8, 4, 2, 1};

 for (int k = 0; k < alot; k++) {
  BitSet.set(increment++, ((array[k] & (bitBytes[k%8]& 0xff)) != 0));
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Literal Syntax For byte arrays using Hex notation..?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450452/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-hex-format-in-java)

Comment: How does a "hexadecimal array" differ from a regular array?  (And what do you expect to accomplish by assigning integers to a float array?)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a good reason to use `float`

Comment: (1) Define 'does not seem to be appropriate'. (2) There is no such thing as a hexadecimal array. There are just arrays, possibly with intial values, which if present may be notated in hexadecimal in the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`byte[] biteBytes = new byte[8];
    for (int j = 0; j < bitBytes.length; j++) {
      bitBytes[j] = (byte) (Math.pow(2,j));

    }`

Comment: But why assign `byte` values to `float` array elements?

Comment: @owlstead - There's no `byte` to "per".

Comment: @HotLicks I tried to answer you in the hope that this would clear things up for you. The floats are used in the original question. It is not done to create a long conversation on the answer of user1198289, and I apologize for creating one here. I've removed my comments, I would recommend you do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hexadecimals is a *representation* of bytes as a `String`, or at least an array of characters. It is mainly used for human consumption, as it is easier to see the bit value of the bytes.

To create a byte array containing byte values, you can use the following construct:

```
final byte[] anArray = { (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x80 };
```

The cast to byte - `(byte)` - is really only required for values of `0x80` or over as bytes are signed in Java and therefore only have values ranging from -0x80 to 0x7F. Normally we only deal with unsigned values though, so we need the cast.

Alternatively, for larger strings, it can be useful to simply supply a hexadecimal string to a decoder. Unfortunately the idiots that have thought out the standard API *still* haven't defined a standard hexadecimal codec somewhere in `java.lang` or `java.util`.

So you can use another library, such as the Apache codec library or a self written function. Stackoverflow to the rescue.

[Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

If you want to have a BitSet of the values in the byte array, please use [`BitSet.valueOf(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#valueOf(byte[]))