# Cannot resolve DatatypeConverter class in java

Tags: java, performance, encryption, types

I have the following code to generate an SHA-1 hash.

```
@Override
    public String generateHash(String plainTextPassword) {

        String hashedPassword = "";
        try {
            MessageDigest msdDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            msdDigest.update(plainTextPassword.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, plainTextPassword.length());
            hashedPassword = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(msdDigest.digest());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("HASHING FAILED");
        }
        return hashedPassword;
    }
```

On my local machine, I have no problem using the DatatypeConverter class. The package is **javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;** When I transfer my project over to a linux machine running Ubuntu, the DatatypeConverter class is not resolved.

Comment: Might this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j Maybe you are using different versions of Java on different maschines?

Comment: I'd try and stay away from that class anyway. The `DataTypeConverter` class is part of an XML framework. It's not supposed to be used as general converter. And it is relatively easy to program this yourself or use Apache Commons or Google Guava. And yes, it is annoying that this functionality is not provided, which I'm going to try and resolve right away.

Comment: As noted by @CodingTil, the JAXB classes were removed from Java SE for Java 11+.

Comment: See the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450452/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-hex-format-in-java for alternative ways to convert bytes to a hex string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The module `javax.xml.bind` has been put outside the jdk as of Java 9.

Also, as part of the donation of Java EE to the Eclipse Foundation, its new name is Jakarta EE and accordingly the namespace was renamed to Jakarta.  So you have to make the following modifications :

Add the dependency to your project :

With Maven, add the following to your `pom.xml` :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

With Gradle, add the following to your `build.gradle` :

```
implementation group: 'jakarta.xml.bind', name: 'jakarta.xml.bind-api-parent', version: '3.0.0', ext: 'pom'
```

And, in your java code where the dependence is used, change the import to :

```java
import jakarta.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
```

Comment: Kotlin gradle import statement:     `implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.1'`